# How does the Amazons "+4 When Attacking" power work?

Tags: small-world

So I got a copy of Small World, and in our first game, the "Amazons" came up early.  According to the rules, they get "+4 when attacking".  What exactly does that mean?  We argued it out and what we eventually decided it meant was

> At the beginning of each of the Amazon player's turns, they receive 4 extra tokens.  When they end their "conquering regions" step, they remove 4 tokens of their choice from the board, then go on to compute VP.

But we're not at all confident in our interpretation.

Comment: I had the same problem. But of course now it make sense. It says 6, +4 on the banner. And if it got the Special Power "Flying +5" the it sums up to 15 Amazons (6+4+5).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Excerpt from the [rule book](http://cdn1.daysofwonder.com/smallworld/en/img/sw_rules_en.pdf) itself:

> **Amazons**
>
> Four of your Amazon tokens may only be
> used for conquest, not for defense, as
> indicated by the +4 on the banner itself. So
> you start your initial turn with 10 Amazon
> tokens (plus any additional ones that may
> be granted to you by the Special Power associated with the
> Amazons, depending on your combo). At the end of each of
> your Troop Redeployments (see Troop Redeployment, p. 5),
> remove four tokens from the map, making sure to leave at least
> one Amazon token in each of your Regions if possible, and only
> take these four tokens back in hand to redeploy on the map
> once you Ready your Troops (see Ready your Troops, p. 6) at
> the start of your next turn.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds right to me.  Compare and contrast to the Ratmen, who get 8 men both "on attack" and "on defense", as it were.  The Amazons are balanced with that race by getting 2 more men (women?) to attack with... but 2 fewer to defend with.

When I started thinking about it that way, it became obviously right that the Amazons should attack with 10 but only defend with 6: the numbers match up nicely!

Answer (score 2):

That's how it worked in the one game I've played.  At the time I felt like it was incorrect in some subtle way, but since it was my first and only game so far, I'm not sure either.